# Separating integers, floats, and scientific numbers as well as names using Python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, text, findall

I have a text file contains meteorological data, which include fields like station name, latitude, temperature, pressure, etc.
All the station's data are in a single line as follows

```
met = 'KIRKENES (CIV/MIL)              -8.666667       5.350000       5.866667      HORNSUND RIVER     ENAN      7.9999998E-02  93  85  2.0000000E-02  0.1600000      4.9999997E-02      -999.9000      -999.9000      8  7  3  22.50000'
```

This should be separated to show them as a list of all data in order, ie.

```
['KIRKENES (CIV/MIL)', '-8.666667',  ... ,'HORNSUND RIVER', 'ENAN', '7.999998E-02', '93', ...., '22.50000']
```

I tried several regular expressions, but I got no luck unfortunately, 
This is a sample when I tried to get the floats and integers only:

```
regex = '^-?\d*(.\d+)?$'
print re.findall(regex, met)
```

but it simply gets nothing!, also I tried this for scientific numbers, and got nothing as well!

```
regexSci = 're.findall('/[+\-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/', met)'
```

Notice that I want a regex to find all forms at once, but sadly I even failed to parse each form separately!

What am I doing wrong? and how to get this done?

Comment: How can you check whether `HORNSUND RIVER`  and `ENAN` are different fields?

Comment: Could you give some more information about the format? Are the columns fixed-width?

Comment: is data in column uses the same size ? maybe you need only slicing - ie. `first_column = met[0:20]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your comment, I separate if it has more than one space.

Comment: Then splitting with 2 or more whitespaces should have been your first thought. Why overcomplicate it with findall? It is easier when the structure is known.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for your comment, Unfortunately, The files have different formats, and the formats are not available, unfortunately.

Comment: Then how can you solve this at all? If you have different, unknown formats, how can you be expected to parse them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you can just *split on 2 or more spaces* with [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: met = 'KIRKENES (CIV/MIL)              -8.666667       5.350000       5.866667      HORNSUND RIVER     ENAN      7.9999
    ...: 998E-02  93  85  2.0000000E-02  0.1600000      4.9999997E-02      -999.9000      -999.9000      8  7  3  22.50000'

In [3]: re.split(r"\s{2,}", met)
Out[3]: 
['KIRKENES (CIV/MIL)',
 '-8.666667',
 '5.350000',
 '5.866667',
 'HORNSUND RIVER',
 'ENAN',
 '7.9999998E-02',
 '93',
 '85',
 '2.0000000E-02',
 '0.1600000',
 '4.9999997E-02',
 '-999.9000',
 '-999.9000',
 '8',
 '7',
 '3',
 '22.50000']
```

Comment: You are really genius. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Watch out, if any string field ever contains a double space, the results won't be as expected.